# How can I automatically round the edges of a popup view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, imageview

I am working on a popup view for an app I am making. If you take a second to look at the image attached below, you will see that the top edges are rounded, but the bottom edges are not. This is because I only rounded the edges of the view (it is lowest in the hierarchy). I cannot round the edges of the images (the colorful boxes) because they are tables in a scrolling view. The only solution I can think of is a very ugly one where I mask the bottom edges with a UIImageView that appears once the popup has faded in. Does anyone have a better solution? If so, I would greatly appreciate your help. Also, my scrolling view is not yet functional, so that is not referenced here and the solution (if functional) should work regardless.

My code:

```
allSeenPopover.layer.cornerRadius = 5
userProfile.layer.cornerRadius = 15
colorBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 15
colorBackground.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]

@IBAction func loadUserProfile(_ sender: Any) {

    if darken.alpha == 0 {

        darken.alpha = 1
        self.view.addSubview(userProfile)
        userProfile.center = self.view.center

        userProfile.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        userProfile.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.largeDropShadow.alpha = 0.3
            self.userProfile.alpha = 1
            self.userProfile.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }

    else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.userProfile.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            self.userProfile.alpha = 0
            self.darken.alpha = 0
            self.largeDropShadow.alpha = 0

        }) { (success:Bool) in
            self.userProfile.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

The image I was referring to: [image]

Comment: Hard to help with what you are doing when we don't _know_ what you are doing. You showed zero code, no explanation of view hierarchy, nothing.

Comment: @matt So sorry! This is my first post, but I should have known better. I will have an updated post in a couple minutes

Comment: @matt It is up (the code)

Comment: What does "because they are tables in a scrolling view" mean?  I can't figure out why this would be a problem.

Comment: To clarify, anything that inherits from UIView, including imageViews, can have their edges rounded with a simple @IBDesignable

Comment: Why is that code even relevant? I don't see anything in it that would round any corners at all.

Comment: @AMayes This is an issue because if I scroll down, the images that are rounded will move out of the scrolling view, leaving new images in their place. Also, the images may only be partially showing which causes further issues with rounding the images themselves.

Comment: @matt Sorry again!!! I forgot this piece (it should be up in a minute)

Comment: Have you tried rounding the corners of the UIImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the view you want rounded is inside a table view cell, you must take care that the view is created added only once per reused cell.

Each time a reused cell scrolls into view, check to see if it has had an imageView subview (using a tag that is unique *within the cell* is a quick way to make that check). If you don't have one, create it and then configure it for the particular row, otherwise just configure it for the particular row...

(warning, I'm not swift fluent, but the idea should be clear)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

    let imageView:UIImageView = cell.viewWithTag(99) as? UIImageView
    if (!imageView) {
        // this code runs just once per reused cell, so setup
        // imageView properties here that are row-independent
        imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.tag = 99  // so we'll find this when the cell gets reused
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        // any other props that are the same for all rows
        imageView.frame = // your framing code here
        cell.addSubview(imageView)
    }
    // this code runs each time a row scrolls into view
    // so setup properties here that are row-dependent
    imageView.image = // some function of indexPath.row

    return cell
}
```